# How to fill cell with concatenated text from other cells? (Error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a cell from a spreadsheet with the text of two other cells from another spreadsheet in the same workbook using the following code:

```
Sub GenerateConsolidado_Clique()
If Sheets("FV List").Range("E26") <> "" Or Sheets("FV List").Range("E26") <> 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidado").Range("C13").Value = "Conector " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FV List").Range(C26) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FV List").Range("D26")
End If
End Sub
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I try to execute this code I get an Error 1004 message (relative to the line inside the if statement). I could not find any post that helped on this problem (maybe because it is a very simple one). Would anyone be able to help me on this?

Comment: You are missing the `"` around `C26`

Comment: Sometimes I can't believe the mistakes I can let pass by. Thank you very much Scott

Comment: Some times an extra set of eyes help.  Do not be offended but this will most likely be closed as a typo.